# for loop limit number of columns but not rows

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, document.write

I have code that loops through and displays through document.write.  I want to limit the display to 3 columns, but unlimited rows.  I will past the code code below, but basically, the space I have to work with is the width of 3 columns but I have more than 3 columns of data.  So I want the loop to stop at 3 and continue on the next row, but have unlimited rows.  Code pasted here:

```
enter code here
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/_SHARED/ApplicationData/Public/FlashWriter.aspx?RotatorGroupID=5357", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("jpg");


document.write("<table border='0' width='675' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>");

document.write("<tr>");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    document.write("<td><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='static' ><tr><td class='HOT969' colspan='3'><a href='");
    document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("link").value);
    document.write("'><img width='190' height='125' class='image' src='");
    document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("image").value);
    document.write("'><br><div class='head'>");
    document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("head").value);
    document.write("</div><div class='copy'>");
    document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("desc").value);
    document.write("</div></a></td></tr></table></td>");
}

document.write("</tr>");

document.write("</table>");
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Usually, you should use `inner.HTML`, but in this case, you should be using `document.createElement()`

Comment: document.write works fine though.  I have 5 items right now and all 5 display in one row, but i want a new row to start after item 3.

Comment: It may work fine, but it is NOT good practice.

Comment: understood, but can you help me with my row issue?

Comment: if my answer helped, would you mind giving it an accept and an upvote if you deem it worthy?

Answer (score 0):

You need another incrementer inside the block of your `for` loop.

Like so:
     
`e = e++;`
Or, you could wrap your for loop in a while loop, make that one the infinite one, and make the for loop stop at 3.
Like so:

```
var e = 0;
while (e < x.length){
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
e = e + 1;
document.write("<td><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' id='static' ><tr>
<td class='HOT969' colspan='3'><a href='");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("link").value);
document.write("'><img width='190' height='125' class='image' src='");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("image").value);
document.write("'><br><div class='head'>");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("head").value);
document.write("</div><div class='copy'>");
document.write(x[i].attributes.getNamedItem("desc").value);
document.write("</div></a></td></tr></table></td>");
}
}

document.write("</tr>");

document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, so an example would be awesome as I am still learning this stuff.

Comment: so what you're saying is make a while loop that is infinite and then a for loop that stops at 3

Comment: Infinite (till you want it to stop at the end of the `x.length`.), @D-Dawgg

Comment: @D-Dawgg, is this what you were looking for?

Comment: yes and no.  It is limiting 3 to the row, but the next row contains the same 3 items instead of displaying items 4 and 5

Comment: so row 1 would have 3 items and row 2 should display the remaining 2 items.

Comment: Put the things you need to display in an array and loop through them

Comment: again, new to this so could you support with an example?